# Limiting Django logging error mails not working in production

Tags: django, email, logging, error-handling, limit

We have a website with several thousand requests per minute and I'd like to limit the maximum number of error admin mails that Django sends us, in case we have an error in our code.

On my local dev system, the following logging configuration works nicely. It sets a cache value, which expires after 10 seconds. An error that occurs within this time interval will not be reported at all. That's what we want. **All of the following code is placed inside our project settings file.**

```
def limit_error_interval(record):
    from django.core.cache import cache
    if not cache.get('last_error'):
        cache.set('last_error', '1', 10) # 10 sec
        return True

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'error_limit': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.CallbackFilter',
            'callback': limit_error_interval
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['error_limit',],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins',],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True
        },
    }
}
```

However, the code fails on our production server (NGINX). limit_error_interval gets called, but every error is still sent by mail. Our cache works within the code, but it appears it's not working inside this function. Is there a problem using cache inside the settings?

This alternative approach/snippet has exactly the same problem: works on local dev system, but not in production.

```
class ErrorIntervalFilter(object):
    def filter(self, record):
        from django.core.cache import cache
        if not cache.get('last_error'):
            cache.set('last_error', '1', 10)
            return True

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1, 'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {'mail_admins': {'level': 'ERROR', 'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler', 'filters': ['error_interval'],}},
    'filters': {'error_interval': {'()': ErrorIntervalFilter,}},
    'loggers': {'django.request':{'handlers': ['mail_admins'], 'level': 'ERROR', 'propagate': True,},},
}
```

Any help or hint appreciated! :-) Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are running several instances of the same application in the production environment (I guess the limit will work per instance).

In my experience, a log aggregation tool like [sentry](https://www.getsentry.com/welcome/) is so much better than receiving errors by email, that it is not worth chasing the cause of your problem. Just install sentry and be happy.

Comment: Thanks Paulo! That was it :-) We had several workers on UWSGI, which all used the cache separately. This also explains some other "strange" behavior in our code, lol. +1 for Sentry. We'll look into it.